# Recursive variadic function template call

Tags: c++

I have these two implementations for a function:

First implementation

```
void print() {}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void print(T first, Ts... args) {
    std::cout << first << '\n';
    print(args...);
}
```

Second implementation

```
template<typename T>
void print(T t) {
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void print(T first, Ts... args) {
    print(first);
    print(args...);
}
```

I would like to ask why in the second implementation the last call to the `print` function
when the `args...` expansion will evaluate to an empty argument list is OK. Outside of the definition of the `print` function there is not possible to call `print()` with no arguments.

I will attach a simple `main` function to make it easy for someone to play with the code.

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

    print("hello"s, 22, "world"s);
}
```

Comment: If you can use C++17 or newer have a look at [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) these will do all the recursive handling for you

Comment: These are not variadic function but variadic templates(or variadic function templates)

Comment: @PepijnKramer OP is not looking for a better way to do this(workaround) but they're specifically asking *"why in the second implementation the last call to the print function when the args... expansion will evaluate to an empty argument list is OK"*. Looks like your mistake run is not over yet :)

Comment: The answer to your qeustion is "because the second implementation is never called with a single argument. Instead the non-variadic version is used for a single argument `template<typename T> void print(T t)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why in the second implementation the last call to the print function when the args... expansion will evaluate to an empty argument list is OK

Because the **second implementation is never called with a single argument.** Instead the non-variadic version `template<typename T> void print(T t)` is used for a single argument.

Basically, `args...` **will never expand to an empty argument list.** because the non-variadic version is available which will be preferred over the variadic version for a single argument function call such as `print("world"s)`.

You can also verify this at [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/26ea3a75)

Answer (score 1):

Example with fold expression :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename arg_t, typename... args_t>
void print(const arg_t& arg, const args_t&... args) 
{
    std::cout << arg << '\n';
    ((std::cout << ", " << args),...); // fold expression : all the recursion happens here
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
    using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
    print("hello"s, 22, "world"s);
}
```

Comment: *"all the recursion happens here"* Except there are no recursions here ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 It did in my mind, but you're right it is iterative. So I stand corrected ;)